# Flexible directory structure for a cross-platform library?

Tags: cross-platform, build-process, directory-structure

I am seeking advice on how to design a flexible and logical directory structure for a cross-platform library. The library is intended to be portable to several UNIX-like operating systems *and* a few processor architectures, with the following criterias:

- OS-specific code;
- CPU-specific code;
- OS- *and* CPU-specific code;
- Ability to override certain files when a specialized implementation exists;
- Few locations to visit when porting.

I believe it'd be wise to push these issues into the hands of a capable building system, but I don't want to risk the directory structure getting complicated in the process. Worth noting is that there's going to be quite a lot of files, of which possibly a third are going to be OS- or CPU-specific, or both.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
bin/
doc/
include/
    ports/
        {linux,freebsd,openbsd,...}/
            {amd64,x86,arm,...}/
                ...
    <shared code>
src/
    ports/
         {linux,freebsd,openbsd,...}/
            {amd64,x86,arm,...}/
                ...
    <shared code>
```

When installing this library, it'd be perfectly fine to copy around headers to allow for prettier code like: `#include <bits/abi.h>` which could be the header for `linux-amd64`.

What is an elegant approach to this potential mess?